React Native TextInput Multiline caret is taking lineheight's height , tried creating custom caret with onSelectionChange but its not working properly
Caret should take font's height and not lineheight's height
image of caret taking up lineheight's height
Have tried implementing custom caret with onSelectionChange property but it's not working properly as its not in sync with the text .
    <TextInput
                ref={inputRef}
                style={customStyle}
                multiline={true}
                textAlignVertical="top"
                value={text}
                maxLength={maxContentLength}
                onChangeText={(value) => handleTextChange(value)}
                onSelectionChange={handleSelectionChange} // Track cursor position
                onFocus={() => {
                    handleInputFocus();
                    setCaretVisible(true);
                }}
                onBlur={() => {
                    setCaretVisible(false);
                    Keyboard.dismiss();
                }}
                returnKeyType="done"
                blurOnSubmit={true}
                caretHidden
            />


   customStyle={{
                                  color: '#8DA3BA',
                                  position: 'absolute',
                                  top: IS_IOS ? -15 : -4,
                                  left: 10,
                                  minHeight: 1000,
                                  paddingTop: 13.5,
                                  paddingBottom: 13.5,
                                  textTransform: 'capitalize',
                                  fontFamily: 'Metropolis',
                                  lineHeight: 45,
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  minHeight: 40
                                }}

